Children playing sports in juvenile jail; title contains "Gear"
I tried to remember a film about child in juvenile jail.
This film has a storyline about children who have problems in their environment and serving time in jail. There they form a sports team (I'm not sure what sport, perhaps the American Football or Baseball) where they have to compete with sports teams by schools outside the jail.
I only remember the part of name of film containing word "Gear".
I'm not sure this is the 1990's or 2000's.

Are you sure it's Gear and not Gridiron Gang from 2006 with Dwayne "The Rock" Johnson?

Teenagers at a juvenile detention center, under the leadership of their counselor, gain self-esteem by playing football together.

Here's the trailer:




You're right. It's not "Gear", but "Grid".
